# how to change dynamic background image in PHP CSS WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

i have a problem..

in admin i have

```
array(
  'id' => 'home_dynamic',
  'type' => 'textarea',
  'title' => __('Dynamic Text', 'lex') ,
  desc' => __('<br />Input each text in the new line.', 'lex'),
),
```

and in `style.css.php` i have this code

```
.home-header {
    background: <?php echo $dark_color; ?> url(' <?php $dynamic2 = get_option( "home_dynamic2" ); echo str_replace( "\n", "[dyn]", $dynamic2 ); ?>') no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

how to modify this code to work ?

Comment: are you sure with `style.css.php` what you want to do with this file?

Comment: _“in admin i have”_ - what does that actually mean? Be specific. You will need a way to _read_ those values in your style.css.php, so where you have _actually_ stored them is rather important. P.S. rather than have this in a specific style.css.php, you might want to use inline styles for stuff like this.

Comment: yep. is dynamic css file. 

style is work corectly. 

but only this code dont work... 


see example 

<?php

 $header_color = get_option( 'header_color' );
 $bg_inner_image = get_option( 'site_inner_bg' );
 $bg_main_image = get_option( 'site_slider_bg' );

?>

.home-header {
 background: <?php echo $dark_color; ?> url(' <?php $dynamic2 = lex_get_option( "home_dynamic2" ); echo str_replace( "\n", "[dyn]", $dynamic2 ); ?>') no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
}